# cursor position requests (CPR) Warning in ipython %pylab via ssh

Tags: matplotlib, ssh, ipython

I get an annoying warning that hangs my `ipython` session (connected by `ssh -X`) when the magic `%pylab` is called during startup.
This is the line responsible:

`get_ipython().magic(u"%pylab")`

in the ipython profile file

`~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-first.py`

This is what the commands look like

```
$ ssh -X myIP
$ ipython

Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 21:52:21) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib

#...hangs here for 10 seconds... and finally:
WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).
In [1]:
```

Strangely, if I remove the file and call `%pylab` within ipython, it still hangs for the same duration but with no warning shown.

Can this be fixed?

My install:

```
Python 3.7.3 
IPython 7.2.0 
matplotlib 3.1.1
qt 5.12.5
pyqt 5.12.3
```

Comment: updated to matplotlib 3.2.1, python 3.7.6, ipython 7.13.0 : it still hangs the same, but with no CPR WARNING